# What does "who doesn’t now and then?" mean?

Tags: meaning

> Whenever we get so upset that we say or do something we later regret
>   (and who doesn’t now and then?), that’s a sure sign that our
>   amygdala—the brain’s radar for danger and the trigger for the fi
>   ght-or-fl ight response—has hijacked the brain’s executive centers in
>   the prefrontal cortex.

I searched the online dictionaries and cann't find any explanation for the phrase above.

So, Could you please tell me what it means?

The full text is here:

http://www.authorstream.com/Presentation/Mukteshwar-1855784-emotional-intelligence-resilience/

Answer (score 1):

"and who doesn't *[do that]*... ?" refers to the action or actions just mentioned. "Now and then" means "sometimes", "occasionally" or "from "time to time". It is a "rhetorical question", which is a question, asked in order to make a statement, that does not expect an answer. In this case the statement is "most people *[do that]* sometimes".

Who doesn't get so upset that they say or does something they later regret (Most people do that sometimes)?.

[Rhetorical question](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rhetorical-question)
[Now and then](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/now-and-then)